# Where should self-created headers reside in Eclipse-cdt?

Tags: include, header-files, eclipse-cdt, include-path

Below is a picture I grabbed off google, and it is actually linked back to a previous Stackoverflow question.

So, on the left (project explorer view) we see an Includes and src directory. I believe the Includes really is just paths to where header files may reside in the file system.

**So now for my question, should header files I have made say "xyz.h" reside in the src folder in an Eclipse project?**

Currently I put them somewhere in the file system on my Linux machine and then path to them (so they show up in the "Includes" for the project), this allows me to edit them in the eclipse editor and so forth, but I believe they are not actually a part of the "Eclipse project".

Not sure there is a right and wrong answer, just looking for what others few as the "best" way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally the header files that you create should be in your project.

The main purpose of the "Includes" mechanism is finding the headers of third-party libraries that your project may use.

You can also use it to specify the location of includes inside your project. For example, you might have an `include` folder inside your project, put all (or some) of your headers there, and configure that as an include path. Eclipse allows you to configure include paths relative to the project, by choosing "Project Path" when adding the include in the project's Paths and Symbols preference page.

As your projects get large, you may eventually want to split them up into several projects, such as an application and supporting libraries. In a case like that, the application's project would have include paths pointing to the headers in the library projects.